# Shell Script: How to Find and Replace the sentence (not a word) recursively inside a folder

Tags: bash, shell

Q. Consider a sample file.txt:

> World Hello world Hello Hell Hello Hello world

How to find and replace the sentence "Hello World" into "Hai Universe"

> World Hai Universe Hello Hell Hello Hai Universe

I'd like to this changes recursively in all the matching files inside a folder.

Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `find` with `sed`:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's|Hello World|Hai Universe|g' {} \;
```

This will find all of the files, recursively, in the current directly and then execute a `sed` find+replace on each file individually.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this, using `sed` command in Unix.

```
sed -i 's/Hello World/Hai Universe/g' filename
```

Comment: this does not always work. especially if your sentence contains slashes (/).

Comment: If your sentence contains slashes `/`, just change the separator character like this:
`sed -i 's_Hello World_Hai Universe_g' filename`